# Calculate age when using ado.net with a sql query?

Tags: c#, ado.net

This is my Select

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con))
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(
            "Select DateOfBirth FROM Patients WHERE HealthNumber='" + cmbHealthNumber.Text+ "'", con);
```

How do I go about calculating the age of the client changing my above code

I try but I never solve this problem...

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: The format of `DateOfBirth` has nothing to do with calculating the age ! Is all you want is to calculate the age ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you using SqlDataAdapter ?

Comment: To find the age of my Patients WHERE HealthNumber =ComboxHealtNumber in  my DB SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to retrieve a single `DateTime`, why not use:

```
string sqlStmt = "SELECT DateOfBirth FROM dbo.Patients WHERE HealthNumber = @No";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, con))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@No", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = cmbHealthNumber.Text.Trim();

   con.Open();
   var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();       
   DateTime dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(result);
   con.Close();
}
```

There's really no need to go through all the trouble of having a `SqlDataAdapter` and a `DataTable` or `DataSet` just for a single value .....

Also: **always use parametrized queries!** - **NO** exceptions. Prevent SQL injection - and you definitely don't want that!

Comment: I don't know if you can make the assumption that the query will only return one result.  I'm not sure the business logic behind `HealthNumber`, but maybe more than one patient has the same `HealthNumber`?  Definitely a consideration before using `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()`.  But I agree, if it is only one value expected then a `SqlDataAdapter()` is a bit overkill.  +1, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your query to this:

```
Select datediff(yy, DateOfBirth, getdate()) FROM Patients WHERE HealthNumber = @HealthNumber
```

By utilizing the [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) method you can make this calculation on the data layer pretty easily.  I also put a variable, `@HealthNumber`, there because you are lending yourself to a SQL Injection attack.  Whether or not that would happen, it is bad practice to hard code values into a SQL query.

This is also assuming that you want to calculate the age in *years*.  If you want it more precise you can change it to any constant value instead of `yy`.  View the reference link above for `DateDiff` to show you all the possible parameter config values.